# replacement for php file_get_contents in smarty template?

Tags: php, youtube-api, smarty, file-get-contents, smarty2

I need to use PHP `file_get_contents()` in smarty tpl file. I can't use it in PHP and assign it to smarty template. Because the URL is generated dynamically through loop inside smarty template file. So I'm using smarty plugin function to achieve that task. But I want to know whether is there any way I can use it in template file directly instead of parsing it from plugin file.

I've attached the plugin code which I'm using to achieve this function. Please anyone let me know how to use it in smarty tpl file directly.

```
function smarty_function_getTitle($params)
{
if ($params['id']) {
    $content = file_get_contents("http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=".$params['id']);
    parse_str($content, $ytarr);
    return $ytarr['title'];
}
}
```

I've used below code to call it in smarty template:

```
{getTitle id=$videoId}
```

Suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Why would you WANT to do this in the template? The point of Smarty is to separate your template code from your PHP code. Smarty plugins exist specifically to do what you have pasted above. That is the beauty of a template engine.

Comment: I know. But my boss refuse to use plugin files. He wants me to do everything in tpl file. It's really crazy to be a coder.

Comment: Eek. I know you don't need to hear it from me but, if your boss is not a developer, he has no place telling you how to code. If he is a developer... He either doesn't know how Smarty works... Or he's not a very good one ;P I'll see if I can think of how to do it in a template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those of you reading that didn't read the comments above, myself and OP are both aware that this is not how you use a template engine. He seems to have his reasons for wanting to do this directly in the template rather than a plugin or ahead of time in his code. So don't slag me for demonstrating how, please :)

Here is how you can do it in Smarty.

```
{"http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=`$videoId`"|file_get_contents|parse_str:$result}
{$result.title}
```

I did the first part all in one call but if you want to be careful you can split it into multiple calls with checks. But I tested this locally and it worked fine.